# How to merge layers and save as an image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I have two layers. The first layer is Image control. The source of it is Bitmap Image. And this is the background layer. The second one, which is the front layer is a canvas on which I can draw geometry objects (such as line, polyline, rectangle etc.) and the background of canvas is transparent.
   How can I merge these two layers and save it as an image using WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "Layers"? Just two controls sat in the same cell of a grid? If you have both "layers" sat in another container (such as a grid, or even the window) then you can use RenderTargetBitmap with that container to get your image. I have some details, an extension method for [taking WPF "Screenshots" on my blog.](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/03/taking-wpf-screenshots/)

Answer (score 0):

You can get bitmap of your parent panel on which you have placed your image control and canvas.

How is the code to get the bitmap of UIElement in WPF.

```
 RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(Width, Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(parentPanel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like, call this method from your canvas (this is canvas) -

```
private Bitmap ImageGenerator()
    {
        var transform = this.LayoutTransform;
        // Call UpdateLayout to make sure changes all changes 
        // while drawing objects on canvas are reflected
        var layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
        layer?.UpdateLayout();
        // Get the size of canvas
        var size = new System.Windows.Size(this.ActualWidth, this.ActualHeight);
        // Measure and arrange the surface
        // VERY IMPORTANT
        this.Measure(size);
        this.Arrange(new Rect(RenderSize));

        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap =
                     new RenderTargetBitmap(
                       (int)this.ActualWidth,
                       (int)this.ActualHeight,
                       96d,
                       96d,
                       PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderBitmap.Render(this);

        JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        // push the rendered bitmap to it
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        encoder.Save(stream);
        this.LayoutTransform = transform;
        return new Bitmap(stream);
    }
```